# WP7 is there a way to access to the RAW data from touch screen?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7 have a lot of cool "helpers", that allow easly to manage user touch, pinch to zoom and so one. But i actually want to get more info (for example size of the finger)

Is there a way to get raw data from touch screen, like regions of contact user fingers, there shape, size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you will get is the [`Touch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728833%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class and it's [`FrameReported`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) static event, but it will not give you the shape of the touch point.

You can use the [`TouchFrameEventArgs.GetTouchPoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchframeeventargs.gettouchpoints%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to get the collection of [`TouchPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchpoint%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instances, which includes the position and size of each touch point.